# Teradata Assistant Database Explorer

Tags: teradata

I am having problems with Teradata Assistant (verion Teradata.Net 13.11.0.1)
The Problem is with Database Explorer window becuse it is fixed length and width and I can´t adjust it as answer window and history window.
Can you please help me with this because the width of the Assistant is very small and when I expand a database I can't see the the column names.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot by chance? Everything I do within my SQL Assistant allows the DB Explorer to remain adjustable. I am using SQL Assistant 13.10.05.

Comment: here is it: http://postimage.org/image/w4tlzqln5/

Comment: I may need to grab the latest version of SQLA and try to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: It looks like you're adjusting only the answer and Query windows. I too am on 13.10.05.04 and I can adjust the DB Column as well as just the Answer and Query Windows. Try mousing over the right edge of the DB column in the Pic you posted.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @apesa - I tried mousing over the edge of the DB Explorer before but it's not working. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Well I know you can Pin and Hide the DB Explorer, but I have not seen your issue with not being able to Not adjust the DB explorer. In fact I can't find an option that locks it in place to begin with. How are you loading the DB Tree? Under Tools -> Options -> DB Tree..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the config file for the tool window(s) has been corrupted.
Try deleting **DBTree.config** or **DockMgr.config** (depending on which version you are using now).

These will be in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Teradata\SQL Assistant
```

Or

```
C:\Users\<username>\Roaming\AppData\Teradata\SQL Assistant
```